# ListView is not updating properly with JavaFX FXML

Tags: java, listview, javafx

In JavaFX I use ListView to display items added or removed to/from a Set. I have made an observableSet to use with the ListView to show the updates but the ListView is not updating properly when the Set changes. Here is my code with a work around. But why it's not working as expected?

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private ListView listView;
    ObservableSet<String> observableSet; //ObservableSet to prevent dublicates
    Integer i = 3;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        observableSet = FXCollections.observableSet();
        observableSet.addAll(Arrays.asList("Item1", "Item2", "Item3")); 
        //Setting up ListView to the ObservableSet
        listView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(observableSet));

    }
    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        observableSet.add("Item" + i++);
       //Setting up ListView to the ObservableSet otherwise it won't update
       //My understanding that I don't have to do this with an observableSet
        listView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(observableSet));
    }
    @FXML
    private void handleRemoveAction(ActionEvent event) {
       observableSet.removeAll(listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
       //Setting up ListView to the ObservableSet otherwise it won't update
       listView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(observableSet));
    }
}
```

The Issue:
I have to keep setting up the ListView as demonstrated above and below everytime the observableSet is updated. Otherwise the change won't show in the ListView.

```
listView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(observableSet));
```

Comment: Is there another a way that I can use to reflect the changes I make to the Set in the ListView?

Comment: hi, I have the same problem and my listview does not update. 2 below answer does not work for me. did u find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behavior. The method you are calling to [create the observable list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-java.util.Collection-) "Creates a new observable list and adds the contents of [the set] to it". So subsequent changes to the set will not change the list.

Another option is just to register a listener with the observable set, and update the list view's items by adding or removing an element appropriately:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private ListView listView;
    private ObservableSet<String> observableSet; //ObservableSet to prevent dublicates
    private int i = 3;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        observableSet = FXCollections.observableSet();

        observableSet.addListener((SetChangeListener.Change<? extends String> c) -> {
            if (c.wasAdded()) {
                listView.getItems().add(c.getElementAdded());
            }
            if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                listView.getItems().remove(c.getElementRemoved());
            }
        });

        observableSet.addAll(Arrays.asList("Item1", "Item2", "Item3")); 

    }
    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        observableSet.add("Item" + i++);
    }
    @FXML
    private void handleRemoveAction(ActionEvent event) {
       observableSet.removeAll(listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try calling

```
listview.refresh();
```

after adding and removing items from the list.

or you can add a change listener on the list and call refresh method from it.
but i prefer first method, because adding a listener sometimes will not update the list view.

Comment: no, refresh is emercency api for extremely rare corner cases (Not for smearing over incorrect model Setup)